# Looking for time travel movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

A young girl travels through time from the attic of her relatives' house and helps her ancestors in many ways; giving glasses for bad eyesight, pills etc.

She also meets a boy who happens to be known in future as a witch hunter.

He saves her when she's accused of witchcraft but as the girl finds out later, he dies instead of her.Then comes the devil who offers her to travel back since she could do it only trice thank to some magic tool that she had.

The girl accepts the deal And is transported to the past, caught and taken to the judge who is none other than the devil himself.

The movie was, I think, European. The main heroine blonde in her teens.

The heroine finds about his death in a local museum.He supposed to be decapitated.

Comment: Welcome to M&TV. Please add anything that can help identify this movie. Like when did you watch it or which country it belongs to or language of the movie or how characters looked like or any other plot details you remember. If you have added any of these details, very good. However, if you recall something, be it as the smallest detail, feel free to [edit](http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/78606/edit) your question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title. Also see [How to Ask Identify-this-X questions](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I found it! For those who are interested, the movie's name is [Oskar & Josefine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0403390/) (2005). Shot in Denmark.

> Josefine gets a time machine for her birthday, and then she travels back in time with her friend Oskar.